# Extending Object.prototype JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am not asking if this is okay:

```
Object.prototype.method = function(){};
```

This is deemed **evil** by pretty much everyone, considering it messes up `for(var i in obj)`.

### The Real Question

Ignoring

- Incompetent browsers(browsers that don't support `Object.defineProperty`)
- Potential for property collision or overriding

Assuming you have some **incredibly** useful method, is this considered wrong/unethical?

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'methodOnSteriods',{
  value: function(){ /* */ },
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false
});
```

If you believe the above is unethical, why would they even implement the feature in the first place?

Comment: Would this defineProperty setting propagate up the prototype chain or only apply to the actual Object.prototype object?  In other words, if you happen to set somevar = {mthodOnSteroids:'mistakeVal'}, will you have lost the define'd settings like 'enumerable: false' for somevar?

Comment: @XHR yup, you do lose your method.   For example `var cards = {forEach:'son'}; cards.forEach(function(){});//world exploids`  And yes you do loose `enumerable:false` for examlpe: `for(var i in cards)console.log(i);` outputs 'forEach'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### UPDATE from 2021

Despite this being the accepted answer, 10 years of experience has taught me this isn't the best idea. Pretty much anything you can do to avoid polluting the global scope is a very very good thing.

Original answer below, for posterity, and because stack overflow will not let me delete an accepted answer.

---

#### Original answer from 2011

I think it's fine if it works in your target environment.

Also I think prototype extension paranoia is overblown.  As long as you use `hasOwnProperty()` like a good developer that it's all fine.  Worst case, you overload that property elsewhere and lose the method.  But that's your own fault if you do that.

Comment: I believe `Object.prototype` specifically can have weird edge-case side effects. But I'm not sure whether that's restricted to legacy browsers. Extending any other prototype is safe.

Comment: Has it been considered to implement `PlainObject`.  Basically `var obj = {};Object.defineProperty(PlainObject,'method',{enumerable:false});obj.methd();`

Comment: "*use `hasOwnProperty()` like a good developer*" - a good developer [does not use `obj.hasOwnProperty(…)`, and shouldn't need to use `hasOwnProperty` at all because `Object.prototype` methods are defined as non-enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572).

Comment: Wow 10 years is a long time. I'm a bit embarrassed by this answer. I should probably delete it.

Comment: 10 years ago, I would probably have upvoted it :-) Things change, and ES6+ has shown us how extending prototypes the wrong way can block language evolution.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say this is *almost* as evil as before. The biggest problem, still the same as before, is that *Object.prototype is global*. While your method might currently be solving world peace, it might have overwriten someone else's method (that was guaranteeing galactic peace) or may be overwritten in the future by some library you have no control over (therefore plunging the world into chaos again)

---

New versions of Javascript have lots of features related to properties, such as definig a property to be enumerable/not enumerable, having getters and setters... Object.defineProperty existis to give control over this.

From [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> This method allows precise addition to or modification of a property
>   on an object. Normal property addition through assignment creates
>   properties which show up during property enumeration (for...in loop),
>   whose values may be changed, and which may be deleted. This method
>   allows these extra details to be changed from their defaults.

---

This new function is basically required to support the new features and you are supposed to use it on your own stuff. Being able to modify Object.prototype is just a side effect of it also being a "normal" object and is just as evil as before.

Comment: Could you reread the question, because I fail to see how this helps?  Modifying `Object.prototype` in both forms is evil, or just one?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @missingno What if the method name consists of 220 random numbers/charecters ? :D Property collision is then highly unlikely :P

Comment: Most of the time a plain old function will do the trick, while being safer and namespaced. If you really need to use it as a method (with `this`) you can use function.apply or function.call.

Comment: I'm assuming you take chaining as an irrelevant arugment.

Comment: Chaining can make code look awesome but it is perfectly possible to live without it.

Answer (score 4):

Well in "JavaScript: the good parts", there is a similar function, i think that is very usefull to improve javascript base objects (like String, Date, etc..), but just for that.

```
// Add a method conditionally. from "JavaScript: the good parts"

Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.hasOwnProperty()` will exclude iteration through inherited properties, which I personally find is often more annoying than helpful. It largely defeats the usefulness of `Object.create()`—which is ironic since the same guy who convinced everyone to do `.hasOwnProperty()` also promoted `Object.create()`.

Object.prototype should not be extended, for the reasons listed here. If you really do want to extend it, then make the extensions non-iterable.

I realize this flies in the face of all of the published best-practices, but we really should stop “mandating” `.hasOwnProperty()` on object key iterations and embrace the usefulness of direct object-to-object inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes, you should do it.

Before doing it, there are several precautions need to take:
1. using `hasOwnProperty` when iterating object, but this isn't really a precautions, when iterating object, I am already using `hasOwnProperty` anyway.
2. check if the `name` in `Object.prototype.name` has existed, this is very safe to avoid name collision.
3. take advantage of `Object.defineProperty()`, just add extra safeguard layer.
As you can see, it's not very complicated. 
Now comes the advantages once you have taken care of the risks/disadvantages:
1. method chaining, this just makes code more readable, terse, and making coding more enjoyable. In turn makes you happier, and your life easier.
2. solves the browser compatibility issue, you are doing polyfill anyway.
P.S.: 
Don't do it when working with a large team for sure.