# What are pitfalls of extending Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

I want to extend Object.prototype, to basically support notifications in JSON data and html elements through UI framework.

```
Object.prototype.setValue = function(key,value){
   // this simply sets value as this[key] = value
   // and raises an event
   Binder.setValue(this,key,value);
};
Object.prototype.getValue = function(key){
   return Binder.getValue(this,key);
};
```

However, based on this question, [Extending Object.prototype JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript) and few others, people say that we should avoid extending Object.prototype, instead any other type is fine.

If I do not do this, then my code becomes bigger, for example

```
window.myModel.setValue("currentStatus","empty");
```

will have to be written like,

```
Binder.setValue(window.myModel,"currentStatus","empty");
```

I want to know what will go wrong if I use these methods? will it cause jQuery to behave unexpectedly? I have seen once, that jQuery's ajax request invokes prototype methods as well (as they references to functions for event handling).

What are other side effects of this? I know it fails for(var x in obj), but mostly we can use obj.hasOwnProperty, that should help right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't want to mess with prototypes from host or native objects.

- You cannot know which side effects it has on any third-party script
- You may confuse third party code
- You don't know if some day those methods are created natively

overall, extending `Object.prototype` effects **any** other object on the entire site. Again, you just don't want to do it, unless, you are in such a sandboxed environment and every single piece of ecmascript is written on your own and you are 100% sure no third-party script is ever loaded.

Answer (score 3):

> I know it fails `for(var x in obj)`, but mostly we can use `obj.hasOwnProperty`, that should help right?

That is the only major pitfall, and `.hasOwnProperty()` helps, but only in your own code.  In jQuery, for example, they've taken the deliberate decision *not* to call `.hasOwnProperty` in the `$.each()` method.

I have used `Object.defineProperty(...)` in my own code to get around the enumerable property problem with no ill-effects (albeit on `Array.prototype`)

Comment: Why did jQuery author made decision not to call .hasOwnProperty, any specific reason? It sure tries to call my event handlers and notifies of changes, however I did get a workaround by checking for arguments.