# Object.create Prototype Chains

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance, object-create

## Initial Question

Yesterday i read about ECMAScript 5 Object.create()
And I wanted to start building prototype Chains in my Code with this method instead of setting the prototype and its constructor,
I like that you can directly set writable configurable etc..

I tried it like this

```
function printobject(msg, obj) {
    if (msg) {
        document.write("<b>" + msg + "</b><br>");
        document.write("<hr><br>");
    }
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (obj[prop].toString() !== "[object Object]") {
                document.write(prop + " : " + obj[prop] + "<br>");
            }
            else {
                document.write("<b>" + prop + " : " + obj[prop] + "</b><br>");
                printobject("", obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (msg) {
        document.write("<br><hr><br>");
    }
};
var base = {
    extend: function () { //extend this Object
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        printobject("Arguments to Extend", args)
        var that = Object.create(this, (args ? args.shift() : {}));
        var arg = args.shift() || {};
        printobject("Copy Properties to New Object", arg);
        for (var prop in arg) {
            that[prop] = arg[prop];
        }
        // Object.freeze(that);       
        return that;
    },
    create: function () { //Creates new instances of the Object
        var that = Object.create(this, {
            extend: {
                value: null,
                writable: false,
                configurable: false
            }, //sets extend and create to null so you cant create a new instance when used create ( use extend instead);
            create: {
                value: null,
                writable: false,
                configurable: false
            }
        });
        that.init.apply(that, arguments); //call init function for the new created object; 
        return that;
    },
    init: function () {
        printobject("No Initfunction supplied for New Object", this);
    } // Empty init function for fallback
}
var Human = base.extend({
    name: {
        value: "test"
    }
}, {
    init: function (name) {
        alert(name + " has been created");
        this.name = name;
    },
    walk: function () {
        alert(this.name + " walks");
    }
});
var Human1 = Human.create("test2");
//alert("Human1 - Name:" + Human1.name);
Human1.walk();
Human.walk = function () {
    alert("Walk has been overwritten")
}; //Object freezed 
Human1.walk();
Human1.create = function () {
    alert("Overwrite create");
}; //Doesnt exist in created     Object
Human1.create(); ?
```

- Do the methods given in `Human` only exist once in the ram? and `Human1.walk()` points to it?
- I wonder if this is the right Approach of doing it like this? I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

This is the code on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VdJN/).

### Answer

First of all, thx a lot that made things def clearer =)
But,
    1: when I do it like this the instances inherit from their constructor's prototype (?)

```
 Nothing = {};
function base() {
this.inherit = function(constructor) {
    alert("inherit");
    var obj = constructor;
    obj.constructor = constructor;
    obj.prototype = this;
   return obj ;  
 }
 ;}
base.prototype = Nothing;
base.constructor = base;
var Top = new base();       
var Human = Top.inherit(function(name) {
        this.name = name;
});
var Paul = new Human("Paul");
alert(Paul.name);
alert(Paul instanceof Human); //true `
```

2: So the instanceof operator doesnt break in this Code , (that it works for functions only seems clear to me)

But written this way, Paul still inherits the inherit() method from Top's prototype
and i would need to overwrite it
But if i dont want the instance of Human to inherit the method, how do i do this ?

And i cant set property descriptors like wrtable except using Objkect.defineproperty (?)

So what are the main benefits from using Object.create() to inherit from Objects vs
Setting the prototypes and construcotrs ? =)

3: Oh thx, yes thats def right thats not an extension of base object =)
 thx for the suggestion =)

Thx for all the effort =)

#### Answer

Ok so when i do

> Nothing = {}
>
> base.prototype = Nothing;

this doesnt prevent s.o to go up the prototype chain til Object.prototype ?
if not , is there a way to do this ? =) Would ( Object.create(null); ) do this,

and i thought that i had to set

> base.prototype.constructor = base;

because otherwise, the prototypes constructor of

> var Top = new base();

would be Nothings' or does'nt base inherit a constructor from somewhere up the prototype chain if the prototype is set to Nothing ->

> Top instanceof base // false

## Update

I ended up doing it in a way like this now:

```
var base = {
// a tiny little selfmade prototypical inheritance system
// you are free to add function arguments for extending the created objects
// neither instanceof nor .constructor is featured, because "classes" are no functions
    create: function(extension,desc) {
        // instances inherit from the proto objects
        var newInst = Object.create(this.proto, desc);
        if(this.proto.childExtendable) //if Subclass allows its Children to be Extendible, do so
            newInst.extend(extension);
        if(newInst.init||this.proto.init) //4
            newInst.init()                          
        return newInst
    },
    inherit: function(props) {
        // the "class" inherits static methods from the class
        var sub = Object.create(this);
        // and the proto objects inherits from the parent proto
        sub.proto = Object.create(this.proto);
        props.protect = this.protect;
        if(props.childExtendable)
            props.extend = this.extend;
        this.extend.call(sub.proto, props);
        return sub;
    }, 
    extend: function (props) {
        for (var prop in props) {
            var propmatch = prop.match(/(.*?)__(.{1,5}?)__(.*)/)||["",prop,"",""];
            this[propmatch[1]+propmatch[3]] = props[prop];
            if(propmatch[2])
                this.protect(propmatch[1]+propmatch[3],propmatch[2]);           
        }
    },
    protect: function(prop,flags) { //with each call it toggles the given flags,  so you can protect funcitons given to the inherit function ;; //This should be available to all childs, but adding it to the base.proto, it changes Object.prototyppe ( therefore not a good idea)
        var d  = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop);
        if (flags.match(/w/)){
             Ti.API.info("Setting writable for propertie " + prop + " in Object " + this + " to " + !d.writable);
             Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {writable:!d.writable});};
        if (flags.match(/c/)){
            Ti.API.info("Setting configurable for propertie " + prop + "in Object " + this);
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {configurable:!d.configurable});};
        if (flags.match(/e/)){
            Ti.API.info("Setting enumerable for propertie " + prop + "in Object " + this);
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {configurable:!d.enumerable});};
        if (flags.match(/a/)){
            Ti.API.info("Setting enumerable for propertie " + prop + "in Object " + this);
            Object.preventExtensions(this);};
   },
    init: function() {},
    proto: Object.prototype // or null, if you want
};

var Human = base.inherit({ //will be put in Human.proto
    childExtendable:true,
    init:function() {alert("Humans Init for all Instances")},
    say:function() { alert("Hi, I'm "+this.name); }
});
Human.proto.name = "default"; // You could use an argument to the inherit function
                              // I just want to make clear what happens
Ti.API.info(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) + "a");
var paul = Human.create({ //extends this object
    name: "Paul",
    test: function() {alert("test")},
    init__wce__: function() {alert("Pauls Own Init")},
    say__w__ : function() { alert("Hi, I'm" + this.name + "s Own Function")}
});
paul.name = "Paul";           // and again, the create function might do it for you
paul.say = function() {alert("Pauls say is overwritten")} // define init without __wce__ and it will be overwritten
paul.say(); // -> "Hi, I'm Paul"
```

Just if anyone cares
However, jsfiddle won't run this, Titanium does everythign as expected
maybe some strict mode (??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do the methods given in Human only exist once in the ram?

Yes.

> and Human1.walk() points to it?

Yes. To be more correct, the prototype of `Human1`, `Human`, has a property "walk" pointing to it.

> I wonder if this is the right Approach of doing it like this? I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

I'd say no, because it is overly complicated, and partly wrong.

- The prototype chain of Human instances includes `base`. Thats odd, and you need to overwrite the create and extend methods for every instance. The usual method is that "classes" contain a "prototype" property, from which their instances inherit.
- Your pattern breaks the `instanceof` operator, although that might be a minor issue.
- The extend method is confusing. It does not extend the object itself, but create a new object inheriting from it and setting properties and property descriptors on that. Better implementation of the same thing:

```
base.inherit = function(descs, props) {
    // creates a new object inheriting from this
    var that = Object.create(this, descs); // will even work when undefined
    if (props)
        for (var prop in props)
            that[prop] = props[prop];
    // Object.freeze(that);       
    return that;
};
```

---

To the extended question:

```
base.prototype = Nothing​;
base.constructor = base;
```

is quite useless. First, the "prototype" property of any function is an (nearly) empty object by default, until you overwrite it. No need to set it to `nothing` :-)

And the "constructor" property is usually a prototype property. It would be inherited by all instances, pointing to thei constructor function. You only need to set it explicitly when overwriting a function's "prototype" property - and you should not set the the "constructor" property on the function itself.

(continuing:) I though more about a solution like this:

```
var base = {
// a tiny little selfmade prototypical inheritance system
// you are free to add function arguments for extending the created objects
// neither instanceof nor .constructor is featured, because "classes" are no functions
    create: function([desc]) {
        // instances inherit from the proto objects
        return Object.create(this.proto, [desc]);
    },
    inherit: function([props]) {
        // the "class" inherits static methods from the class
        var sub = Object.create(this);
        // and the proto objects inherits from the parent proto
        sub.proto = Object.create(this.proto);
        [Object.extend(sub.proto, props);]
        return sub;
    },
    proto: Object.prototype // or null, if you want
};

var Human = base.inherit();
Human.proto.name = "default"; // You could use an argument to the inherit function
                              // I just want to make clear what happens
Human.proto.say = function() { alert("Hi, I'm "+this.name); };

var paul = Human.create();
paul.name = "Paul";           // and again, the create function might do it for you
paul.say(); // -> "Hi, I'm Paul"
```

This way, `paul` inherits from `Human.proto` inherits from `base.proto` which is `Object.prototype` or `null`. And `Human` inherits from `base`, i.e. you could easily build a "subclass" with `Human.inherit()`.

Whether you want to use property descriptors or not is absolutely your choice. Everywhere you create something and extend it, you might use `Object.defineProperties` (or the second argument to `Object.create`) as well as `Object.extend` (the usual for-in-copy-method).

> what are the main benefits from using Object.create() to inherit from Objects vs Setting the prototypes and construcotrs?

It's a design choice. `Object.create` won't call a [constructor] function on the built object. See [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/1048572) or [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166616/1048572) for further information.

> `base.prototype = {};` doesnt prevent s.o to go up the prototype chain til Object.prototype?

Yes. An empty object (as created by your literal) still has `Object.prototype` in its chain. The only way to do this is `Object.create(null)` (not shim-able with `new`).

> i thought that i had to set `base.prototype.constructor = base;`

Not in this case. Having a `function base(){...}`, setting its "prototype" property to `{constructor: base}` changes absolutely nothing (except that "constructor" in enumerable now) - every function has such a default proto object including the "constructor".

So only when you need to overwrite the "prototype" property with a new object, as it happens when letting it inherit from another function's prototype, you might add this convenience property: `MySubClass.prototype = Object.create(MyClass.prototype, {constructor:{value:MySubClass}});`

> otherwise...

Nothing would happen. The "constructor" property on prototype objects is needed for no language features (like `instanceof`), and is seldom used. It's likely that nothing breaks.

Comment: You can't format code in the comments. You should delete them and add the code to your question by editing it.

Comment: The instanceof operator works only for Function objects. Try `Human1 instanceof Human` with you original code.

Comment: Thnx =) Edited the Answer,
Yes in the Original Code it doesn't works =)
I wouldnt understand anyway why it should work on anything than a construcotr, would seem not right in my mind

Comment: OK, i've answered a first part. Hope to answer all the rest of your questions later.

Comment: Thx a lot =) I appreciate it , that really helps me in understanding javascript a bit better =) 
oh yes thats right, that was an mistake i meant to do base.prototype.constuctor, happens to me often and the most times i dont  realize itbefore running,
Wouldnt make any sense at all, setting the constructor to the constructor itself (?)

Comment: ( do ig get this right , the function itself is in the functions prototype constructor propertie ?)

Comment: Wow *.* thank you so much =)
Really nice and understandable Answer, 
I even understood that code on the first read, thx to your comments,
And not only that, i was looking quite a time for sth like Object.extend() , this is awesome =)

I read those two links before , but that didnt made those things for Object.create that clear in my mind =)

Thx again, i never expected such an helpfull answer,
I really appreciate the effort you put into explaining all this =)
This is how learnign javascript is even more enjoyable;

Comment: Object.extend is not a native function, but you will find a version of it in each common library...

Comment: oh ok =) but i could set Object.prototype.extend = function () {...}
using for in loops as you mentioned =) 
// would that apply to any kind of object since anything in javascript is an "Object" (isit?) ?

Comment: Yes, and that is a problem. [What are pitfalls of extending Object.prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8341123/1048572)