# How to Add Static Members in EcmaScript 5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to add a static function to a class in EcmaScript 5 JavaScript. My class definition looks as follows:

```
var Account = {};

Object.defineProperty(Account, 'id', {
    value : null
});
```

And I would create a new instance like this:

```
var theAccount = Object.create(Account);
theAccount.id = 123456;
```

Now I want to add a static function to the `Account` class. If I had created the `Account` class using a constructor function and the `prototype` property like this:

```
var Account = function () {
    this.id = null;
};
```

...I could just do:

```
Account.instances = {};

Account.createInstance = function () {
    var account = new Account();
    account.id = uuid.v4();
    Account.instances[account.id] = account;
    return account;
};
```

But since I am using `Object.defineProperty` and not the `prototype` property to add members, `Account.instances` and `Account.createInstance` would also be instantiated when calling `Object.create` and therefore be properties of the instance.

How do i add a static member to a class when using EcmaScript 5 style object creation?

Comment: Well-asked, and interesting, question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

> My class definition looks as follows `var Account = {};`

That's not a class (if we would call the classical model like that), but just a **prototoype object**. And as you only have that, you will need to use other variables for static members like an instances-cache or a create function:

```
var Account = {...};
var instances = [];
function createAccount(){...}
```

You could namespace them, of course:

```
var Account = {
    proto: {...},
    instances: [],
    instantiate: function create(){...}
};
```

...but that looks very close to the classical pattern, doesn't it? The only difference would be that you had a `create` function on a namespace object instead of a constructor function *as* the namespace object.

You might also be interested in the question [Object.create Prototype Chains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240011/1048572), where [I have discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243549/1048572) a full inheritance model working like that, with `create` and `inherit` methods that all "class objects" inherit from a `base`.

---

Further answer on your question in the comments:

> Doesn't Object.create make the new operator obsolete in EcmaScript 5?

No. The [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) does two things: Set up the prototype chain of the new instance, and apply the the constructor function. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/) does only the first thing, so you can use it when you dont need a function (or dont want it to execute).

In your case, you have such a function, so the classical model wouldn't be wrong here as well. See also [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/1048572).

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to read some more articles on it to fully understand what each object creation method does. This post was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

For ES 5 if you want static methods:

```
// A static method; this method only 
// exists on the class and doesn't exist 
// on child objects
Person.sayName = function() {
    alert("I am a Person object ;)");  
};

// An instance method; 
// All Person objects will have this method
Person.prototype.setName = function(nameIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;  
}
```

see @https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/30/static-and-instance-methods-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some different things mixed up. The prototype is going to be shared fallback properties. If you want to define a static (I assume by what you're doing you mean non-writable property?) you can use defineProperty in the constructor.

```
function Account(){
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
    value: uuid.v4()
  });
  Account.instances[this.id] = this;
}

Account.instances = {};

Account.prototype.id = null;


var account = new Account;
```

Comment: Thanks @benvie. But what if I want to use `Object.create` to create objects instead of `new`? Doesn't `Object.create` make the `new` operator obsolete in EcmaScript 5?

Comment: @MaxKueng - no, they do different things. `Object.create()` is for dealing with 'classes' (not really classes) declared as objects, while `new` is for instantiation, which is always of functions, i.e. constructors.

Comment: Object.create is for when you want to create an object but not initialize it. If you want to initialize it then use a constructor, that's the whole point of a constructor. Object.create is even implemented using `new` in the V8 source code. `var obj = new  $Object(); obj.__proto__ = proto;`  https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/v8natives.js#L1038

Comment: @benvie: I don't think you could say that. It is implemented using the `__proto__` property, and they could've use `{}` instead of `new $Object();` as well.

Comment: `{}` is the same thing as `new Object` except it's not susceptible to being overridden. That's the point I was making. Avoiding the `new` keyword for the sake of avoiding it is pointless, there's no benefit. You're doing it one way or another.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `Object.create` was the new `new`. I will read some more about both of them. It probably doesn't make to use `Object.create` just for the sake of it. I really like `Object.defineProperty` with getters and setters. But I think I can also use them on the prototype with constructor functions. Lets see.

Answer (score 1):

> But since I am using Object.defineProperty and not the prototype
>   property to add members, Account.instances and Account.createInstance
>   would also be instantiated when calling Object.create and therefore be
>   properties of the instance.

Any static properties or methods declared on the source object will not be deemed properties of the instance - they will be read from the prototype.

```
    var obj = {};
    obj.static = function() { alert('hello'); }
    var instance = Object.create(obj);
    instance.ownProperty = 'hello';
    alert(!!instance.static); //true - it has .static
    alert(instance.hasOwnProperty('static')); //false - but it's not its own
    alert(instance.hasOwnProperty('ownProperty')); //true
```

Comment: Wooooh! I have just learned that `!!` will convert something to a boolean without negating it. Thanks. Never thought of this.

Comment: Yeah it's a trick to test something's [truthy](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Apr/Twisted-logic-understanding-truthy-and-falsy-174) value.