# Not sharing object properties in OLOO inheritance

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure on the best approach to have object properties that are individual for each object in a OLOO inheritance chain.

Check this fiddle or consider the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19413/

```
Parent = {
    array: [],

    add: function(element) {
        this.array.push(element + this.array.length.toString());
        return this;
    },

    getAll: function() {
        return this.array;
    }
};

Child = Object.create(Parent, {
    removeAllButOne: { value: function() {
        this.array.splice(1);
        return this;
    }}
});

foo = Object.create(Parent);
foo.add('foo');

bar = Object.create(Child);
bar.add('bar');
```

In the fiddle a click on the foo or bar text will call the foo.add(...) or bar.add(...) function to add an element to the objects array, resulting in one extra `<p>` tag in the output.
The result is not what I want. Both foo and bar share the same array. But its easy to understand what happens, if we look up the object inheritance we can see the following:
[image: inheritance]

Ok then, what can I do go get around this? There were two options that came to my mind:

**Option 1)**
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19419/

```
Parent = function() {
    return {
        array: [],

        add: function(element) {
            this.array.push(element + this.array.length.toString());
            return this;
        },

        getAll: function() {
            return this.array;
        }
    };
};

Child = Object.create(Parent(), {
    removeAllButOne: { value: function() {
        this.array.splice(1);
        return this;
    }}
});

foo = Object.create(Parent());
foo.add('foo');

bar = Object.create(Child);
bar.add('bar');
```

This would create a new Parent object, creating all the functions of the Parent object each time a Parent object is created or a child "inherits" from a (new) Parent object. While this solves the problem I had, it seems like a bad idea to always recreate the same functions over and over again for each child type object.

**Option 2)**
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19420/

```
Parent = Object.create({
    add: function(element) {
        this.array.push(element + this.array.length.toString());
        return this;
    },

    getAll: function() {
        return this.array;
    }
}, {
    ctor: { value: function(someArgs) {
        this.array = [];
        // maybe use someArgs
        return this;
    }}
});

Child = Object.create(Parent, {
    removeAllButOne: { value: function() {
        this.array.splice(1);
        return this;
    }}
});

foo = Object.create(Parent).ctor();
foo.add('foo');

bar = Object.create(Child).ctor();
bar.add('bar');
```

This seems to also solve the problem but avoids the recreation of the Parent object and its functions. So is this the way to go? What if I had multiple children in the inheritance chain that also have private properties?

Something like this?

```
Child = Object.create(Parent, {
    ctor: { value: function(someArgs) {
        this.__proto__.ctor(someArgs);
        this.otherPrivate = {};
        // maybe use someArgs
        return this;
    }},

    removeAllButOne: { value: function() {
        this.array.splice(1);
        return this;
    }}
});
```

Children would be shadowing the parent ctor with their own function... but in their ctor function they could call the parents ctor to not break functionality.

Thoughts and advice is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10131052/1048572). Yes, use constructors.

Comment: If you're willing to use a library, [stampit](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit) may help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use *Constructors* so *array* is always created as an *own property* on the instance

```
// define Parent
function Parent() {
    this.array = []; // array will be an instance property
}
Parent.prototype = {}; // inherit all the goodies from Object.prototype
Object.assign(Parent.prototype, { // using `Object.assign` for shorthand
    add: function (element) {
        this.array.push(element + this.array.length.toString());
        return this;
    },
    getAll: function () {
        return this.array;
    }
});

// define Child
function Child() {
    Parent.apply(this); // apply Parent constructor to the instance
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); // inherit Parent's prototype chain
Object.assign(Child.prototype, {
    removeAllButOne: function () {
        this.array.splice(1);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Now have

```
var a = new Child(),
    b = new Child();
a.array === b.array; // false
```

---

You could also write this using *ES 6's* classes, but that is just syntactic sugar for what I've written above and will result in the same structures.

Comment: I don't think you really want `Parent.prototype = Object.create(null);`. Inherit from `Object` maybe?

Comment: @Bergi when setting up my own structures I usually like having control over the whole chain. Is there some advantage to inheriting from `{}` instead of `Object.create(null)`? `typeof (new Parent); // "object"` in either case. If it's meant to be concatenated with a _String_ or something then (again personally) I prefer an _Error_ telling me I've forgotten to implement a _toString_ than a silent `"[object Object]"`

Comment: I think `.hasOwnProperty()` and `.isPrototypeOf()` from `Object.prototype` are quite valuable in pure inheritance (also, `instanceof Object`). But sure, it's up to you whether you want `Object` or not. I'd bet there are many libraries that will break when you use non-`Object`-objects everywhere :-)

Comment: Yes, I can imagine breaking libraries everywhere, I'll update for OP. Back to personal preference though, I never trust `hasOwnProperty` except via `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` (maybe I'm paranoid) and haven't really needed `.isPrototypeOf` over `instanceof` before

Comment: I believe the whole idea behind OLOO is that constructors should be avoided.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yeah, my personal preference is to use `hasOwnProperty.call` as well, but I rarely see it elsewhere.

Comment: @joews: In the "pure" idea of OLOO there is no `array: []` in the `Parent`, instead you do `var instance = Object.create(Parent); instance.array = [];`. To avoid repeating ourselves, we use factories (or wait, did someone call that "constructor"?).

Comment: @Bergi with the goal of removing `obj.constuctor.prototype` indirection, so factories are not quite equivalent.

Comment: @joews if you don't define _constructor_ on the _prototype_ you cannot access `obj.constructor` in the way you describe (try with the code here, you will get `Object` because it's inheriting from `Object.prototype` but not `Child` or `Parent` because we didn't define a _constructor_ property)

Comment: @joews: I would not call that an indirection. The factory somehow has to know which prototype to create the object from, and a public `.prototype` property is better than a hidden closure variable. Oh, and I didn't mean to limit the term "constructor" to functions that are called with `new`.

Comment: @joews: There are many looks this pattern can take, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11243549/1048572). Now make `.create` implicitly call a `.constructor()` method of the object if there is one :-)

Comment: @Bergi by indirection I mean that not all properties can be reached by traversing up `prototype` properties - it can be harder to explain where any given property is defined. E.g. in this code I can't even find the path from `a` to `getAll`.

Comment: Not arguing against this pattern BTW; trying to wrap my head around arguments for/against OLOO.

Comment: @joews `a` inherits an _Object_ `C` (which we called `Child.prototype`), `C` inherits an _Object_ `P` (which we called `Parent.prototype`). `P` has property _getAll_

Comment: @PaulS. thanks. I had some misconceptions about `prototype`/`Object.getPrototypeOf` and `constructor`, which this discussion has helped to clear up.

Comment: While this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, this answer and the bottom answer both show me the options and tradeoffs of different patterns. I'm gonna vote this for the correct answer, it helped me alot and got me thinking more about `.isPrototypeOf` and `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

[OLOO](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md) favours composition over inheritance. You could use a factory method pattern with `Object.assign` to compose objects with simple prototype delegation:

```js
// Composable prototype objects, or "traits"
var base = {
  add: function(element) {
    this.array.push(element + this.array.length.toString());
    return this;
  },

  getAll: function() {
    return this.array;
  }
};

var canRemoveAllButOne = {
  removeAllButOne: function() {
    this.array.splice(1);
    return this;
  }
}

// Factory functions
// You could think of these like external constructors
function createBase() {
  return Object.assign({}, base, {
    array: []
  })
}

function createComposed() {
  var base = createBase();
  return Object.assign(base, canRemoveAllButOne)
}

// Test
function log(s) {
  document.write(s + "<br>");
}

var b1 = createBase();
var b2 = createBase();
var c1 = createComposed();
var c2 = createComposed();

b1.add(1);
b1.add(2);
b2.add(9);

c1.add('a');
c2.add('b');

log(b1.getAll());
log(b2.getAll());
log(c1.getAll());
log(c2.getAll());
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never tried this pattern in real code, and I don't particularly like the way that `base` and `canRemoveAllButOne` assume the presence of `this.array` without creating it themselves.

Comment: I thought OLOO favours behavior delegation while still maintaining and using the prototype link. But in your code you're not using the prototype link in the usual way. EDIT: strike that, I think I understand now.

Comment: No, you're right. I had somehow conflated OLOO with "concatenative inheritance" (which does go hand-in-hand with OLOO). A real OLOO approach would look like `Object.assign(Object.create(parent), childAttributes)`. I'll update the answer later to make this clear.