# Looping Through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object:

```
 var json = {"Mike":1, "Jake":1, "Henry":1};
```

I am trying to loop through this list to access the names. Currently I am using:

```
for (var name in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        console.log(name);
    }
}
```

But it's not printing the name. Is that the correct way to do it?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bKwYq/

Comment: Working for me, code looks fine. You realize console.log() prints to a debugger console and not to your page, yes?

Comment: This works me and prints the name correctly.

Comment: It should print the names. Is it a browser issue?

Comment: @Interrobang Yes. In the console though I am seeing the number 1. Very strange.

Comment: Note that there is no JSON here whatsoever. JSON is a _text-based_ data format that is based on, is named after and _looks like_ this fundamental syntax of Javascript that you're using, which could be called Object Notation.

Comment: which browser & version?

Comment: Side note: that is not a [JSON object](http://json.org); that is a JavaScript object literal. A JSON object would look like: `var json = '{"Mike":1, "Jake":1, "Henry":1}';`

Comment: He is asking how to print the names, he's not telling you that this example does not output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

As other people mentioned, [this is not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), it's just an object.

The hasOwnProperty thing may not really be necessary here also.

```
var persons = {"Mike":1, "Jake":1, "Henry":1};
for (var name in persons) {
    alert(name);
}
```

This will work in every browser: http://jsfiddle.net/HsNMY/

Comment: It will not work as intended if you add `Object.prototype.foo = 42` before your loop. This is why `hasOwnProperty` is recommended.

Comment: it's super recommended to not add anything to Object.prototype.foo, so all major libraries don't.

Comment: While I know that some major libraries forbid it (because they don't want to add `hasOwnProperty` in all their enumerations due to the speed hit), I'd like you to provide a citation for "super recommended".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/ http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/ Extending natives I think is cool though, just not Object.prototype. This is great talk about it:  http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I personally find only the second URL convincing; the first is just a random opinion, and the third appears to be written by someone who clearly didn't understand how to write JavaScript code. Still, you have provided a citation as asked. :)

Comment: :) that video i posted about extending natives goes pretty deep into it though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by getting the key using Object.keys and then using foreach loop to print to console or display as alert message.

```js
var persons = {"Mike":1, "Jake":1, "Henry":1};
var keysInPerson= Object.keys (persons);
keysInPerson.forEach ((name) => console.log (name));

//Alert
keysInPerson.forEach ((name) => alert (name));
```

Answer (score -2):

The correct way to PRINT the name is to use `document.write` instead of `console.log`, as in this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/jRAna/

Comment: console.log is actually a nicer way to debug rather than printing to the page

Comment: wow so much hatred simply by responding to the actual question. Never said it was better to print it, just answered what was asked.