# jQuery JavaScript is there a function like parseInt for Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, I know, sounds silly, but I am having this one variable passed around and around and I think somewhere in the midst of it all its losing itself as a Boolean Value, that being the case I need to take said string when it comes to one portion of my script and make sure its read as a Boolean. So with that, I am wondering if theres something like the parseInt function but for booleans cause I know when my int's manage to get run through the mill and turn into a string cause of, I sometimes need to invoke a means of making it recognize as integer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.prototype.parseBoolean = function ()
{
  return ("true" == this.toLowerCase()) ? true : false
}
```

Comment: adding to native objects prototype is generally frowned upon these days http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript - also can be simplified by getting rid of the ternary statement and just returning the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

no there is no function, there is this shortcut:

```
var bool = !!something;
```

or, you can make a new boolean like this:

```
var bool = Boolean(something)
```

it works by coercing the value to a boolean. It will use the truthy/[falsy](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9780596517748/awful-parts/falsy_values) value for the variable.

while i am on this topic, there is also:

```
var floor = ~~3.1415; //floor = 3
```

Comment: Warning if anyone stumbles on this: !!"false" === true. And Boolean("false") === true.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringToBoolean(string){
    if (typeof string === "undefined") {
        console.log("stringToBoolean Undefined Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof string === "boolean") return string;
    switch(string.toLowerCase()) {
        case "true": case "yes": case "1": return true;
        case "false": case "no": case "0": case null: return false;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```