# Extending Object with a Non-Enumerable Property

Tags: javascript, node.js, should.js

I was reading the `readme` for [should.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/) and got to the "OMG IT EXTENDS OBJECT???!?!@" section which says

> > Yes, yes it does, with a single getter `should`,
> >     and no it won't break your code,
> >     because it does this properly with a non-enumerable property.

I've always heard you shouldn't extend the `object` prototype but never really understood why.

Can someone explain why, in general, extending `object` is bad (what can it break)? And also explain what a non-enumerable property is and how this helps?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript for some discussion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with extending `Object.prototype`. If the extension is enumerable, then it will be encountered in every enumeration of every object when using `for-in`.

```
Object.prototype.foo = "bar";

var empty_object = {};

for (var p in empty_object) {
    alert(p + " " + empty_object[p]);
}
```

Clearly this can mess with your code. You can use `.hasOwnProperty()` in every enumeration of every object property, but there's a performance impact. Also sometimes you actually *want* to include inherited properties in your enumeration, but this makes it impossible, or at least very tough.

---

You should also note that just because the property is marked non-enumerable, *that doesn't mean that it won't break your code*.

What if you have an object, and you need to get the value of the `.should` property if it exists? *(Where `.should` is expected to have some other meaning in the code.)*

```
var val = my_object.should;

if (val) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Trouble is that the `.should` property will now always return the value of the inherited property if there isn't one directly on `my_object`.

This issue exists for the native `Object.prototype` extensions, but at least those names are commonly known, and therefore habitually avoided.

---

It's good that the library documented this extension, but it's still pretty short-sighted to claim that it won't break your code.

Least they could do would be to make it an optional extension.