# Extend Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi I want to sort a native array by a date that I get back from mysql. I want to extend the native array, so I don't have to type the same method over and over again

how can I achieve that?

here's my sorting:

```
[...].sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.timestamp) - new Date(a.timestamp);
});
```

Comment: You can extend Array prototype. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945675/extending-array-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: Why not just declare your sort function as an external function and just pass it every time you call sort? Like: `[...].sort(sortByDate)`. You should be careful about overwriting existing functions because other libraries or code you use might depend on it.

Comment: `function sortByDate(a, b) { return ... } /* .. */ [...].sort(sortByDate)`

Comment: if I run it I get this: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined

Comment: Sort by `timestamp` is oddly specific and it seems unnecessary to pollute the prototype with this. You could create a generic `compareFunction`. Even that seems like overhead. `[...].sort((a, b) => new Date(b.timestamp) - new Date(a.timestamp))` is readable for he next person reading the code than checking some other file to see what's going on

Comment: and what should I do then?

Comment: Why not do the sorting in your MySQL query?

Comment: Most people are of the opinion that extending the prototype of native objects is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). If you're a beginner, I'd recommend not getting into that habit. @adiga I doubt something like `array.sort(byTimestamp)` would confuse anyone looking at it. And if you're using something like VSCode, hovering over it or alt clicking the function will show you its definition. I'm pretty sure there's no overhead difference either.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% convinced that this is really better than just passing an array to function… but you can wrap the sort in a function and put it on the array prototype. This has the convenience of just being able to call it with `dateSort()` but lack the flexibility of passing in a callback:

```js
Array.prototype.dateSort = function(desc = true) {
    this.sort((a, b) => {
      if (!desc) [a, b] = [b,a]
      return new Date(b.timestamp) - new Date(a.timestamp);
    });
  }

// Prevent dateSort from showing up when iterating over object keys:
 Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'dateSort',{
    enumerable: false
  });

let arr = [
  {timestamp: '1995-12-17T03:24:00'},
  {timestamp: '1995-12-17T01:24:00'},
  {timestamp: '1995-12-17T02:24:00'},
  {timestamp: '1995-12-17T00:24:00'}
]

arr.dateSort()
console.log(arr)

arr.dateSort(false)
console.log(arr)

for (let i in arr){
 // no datesort when enumerating
 console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: Yes @bambam  -- I wasn't certain of the format of the timestamps since it's not mentioned in the OP.

Comment: yeah. Noticed that now . Fixed it now.

Comment: To make that more generic, call the method sortBy and let them pass in a key to sort by

Comment: (_Yes it's a bad idea but I still see `for...in...` used with arrays, hence..._) `for (var x in arr) { console.log(x); }` will also print `dateSort`

Comment: Why I can't use that extension, when I put it in another file

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS That depends on how you're pulling that other file into your script. You might need to add details to the question to answer that well.

Comment: Why I have to pull it? Javascript is so confusing sometimes when on other languages you haven't think about it

Comment: how can I pull that file?