# Nested recursive object loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, recursion

I have arrays of objects that can also have arrays of their own. My main goal is to find an object with a given id in the whole tree and  get readmap to that element by displaying the names of the objects names where it occurs.

For example I have data object like this:

```
{
  id: '0',
  name: "Boys"
  children: [
   {
    name: "Soldiers",
    children: [
     {
       name: "Bravo"
       children: [
         {name: "Tom"},
         {name: "Andrew"}
       ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    name: "Runners",
    children: [
     {
       name: "Team B"
       children: [
         {name: "Mark"},
         {name: "David"}
       ]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

I am currently finding an item by a function

```
 function findByName (name, array) {
    for (const node of array) {
      if (node.name === name) return node;
      if (node.children) {
        const child = findByName(name, node.children);
        if (child) return child;
      }
    }
  }
```

But to achive my goal I need also roadmap to that value. For example.

When I want to find `"Tom"`. Besides results of `findByName` I would like to get `{name: "Tom", road: ["Boys", "Soldiers", "Bravo"]`

Comment: Reopened.  The [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25403781) has a different structure, with descendants as Object properties rather than the `children` array.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass down another property which handles the path. Start by defining path as an empty array. And since you only care about the **name**, you can push the name into this array everytime you find a node that has children.

Then you just keep passing the updated array to your recursive function. See my working example below:

(I updated your function to return an object which contains both the result and path)

```
function findByName(name, array, path = []) {
  for (const node of array) {
    if (node.name === name) return {result: node, path};
    if (node.children) {
      path.push(node.name) // We update the path with the current node name that has children
      const child = findByName(name, node.children, path );
      if (child) return { result: child, path};
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:
https://jsitor.com/VnktoLq49

Answer (score 1):

You could add the path for every leve in the calling function without handing over the path.

```js
const
    findByName = (array, name) => {
        for (const node of array) {
            if (node.name === name) return { ...node, path: [] };
            if (node.children) {
                const child = findByName(node.children, name);
                if (child) return { ...child, path: [node.name, ...child.path] };
            }
        }
    },
    data = [{ id: '0', name: "Boys", children: [{ name: "Soldiers", children: [{ name: "Bravo", children: [{ name: "Tom" }, { name: "Andrew" }] }] }, { name: "Runners", children: [{ name: "Team B", children: [{ name: "Mark" }, { name: "David" }] }] }] }];

console.log(findByName(data, 'Tom'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like generators for this kind or problem because it allows you to `select` one, many, or all results. Additionally generators give control to the caller, allowing you to stop searching whenever you are satisfied with the result. This can be accomplished with a single function -

```js
function* select(a = [], query = Boolean, path = [])
{ for (const t of a)
  { if (query(t)) yield { ...t, path }
    yield *select(t.children, query, [...path, t.name])
  }
}

const data =
  [{ id: '0', name: "Boys", children: [{ name: "Soldiers", children: [{ name: "Bravo", children: [{ name: "Tom" }, { name: "Andrew" }] }] }, { name: "Runners", children: [{ name: "Team B", children: [{ name: "Mark" }, { name: "David" }] }] }] }]

// select "Tom" OR "Mark"
for (const r of select(data, v => v.name == 'Tom' || v.name == "Mark"))
  console.log("found:", r)
```

```js
found: {
  "name": "Tom",
  "path": [
    "Boys",
    "Soldiers",
    "Bravo"
  ]
}
found: {
  "name": "Mark",
  "path": [
    "Boys",
    "Runners",
    "Team B"
  ]
}
```

If you want only the *first* result, we can use `return` or `break`, and searching stops immediately, potentially saving many wasted computations -

```js
function first (it)
{ for (const x of it)
    return x              // <- return and stop searching
}

first(select(data, v => v.name == "Andrew"))
```

```js
{
  "name": "Andrew",
  "path": [
    "Boys",
    "Soldiers",
    "Bravo"
  ]
}
```

If you want *all* of the results, we can use `Array.from`. Because `select` is flexible, it allows us to do all sorts of useful queries -

```js
Array.from(select(data, v => !v.children), r => r.name)
```

```js
[
  "Tom",
  "Andrew",
  "Mark",
  "David"
]
```

Comment: I knew there was a good reason to reopen this!  I wrote several different answers, none which seemed to offer anything great, so I didn't post them.  I'm entirely unsurprised to have you come through with an elegant answer!  One quibble: the name `find` to me is too tied to `Array.prototype.find` with its short-circuiting return.  Something like `select`, `query`, or `match` strikes me as clearer.  I especially like `select`.

Comment: I'm delighted to make a valuable contribution ^_^ I also like `select`, updating the answer now