# jQuery find() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a pretty typical form with some inputs and a submit button, however when I try to use jQuery's `find()` method, I get some annyingly inconsistent results. The are as follows:

```
$("#frmContact").find(":submit") -> undefined is not a function  
$("#frmContact").find(".btn") -> works
$("#frmContact").find(".btn.secondary") -> undefined is not a function
$("#frmContact").find("input[type=submit]") -> works
$("#frmContact input:submit") -> undefined is not a function
$("input[type=submit]", "#frmContact") -> undefined is not a function
$("form").find("input") -> works
$("form").find("input[type=submit]") -> undefined is not a function
```

What's going on here and how do I fix this?

I'm using jQuery 1.11 after upgrading from 1.9 hoping that it will fix the issue. There's also Angular on the page and I'm calling this code from the console after everything is loaded.

My form, just in case you need it is as follows **[EDIT]** updated to show actual HTML output with Angular classes and directives:

```
<form ng-submit="saveContact($event, '/applicants/update_contact?id=1593')" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" _lpchecked="1" id="frmContact">
   <h4 class="section-header">Applicant Contact Information</h4>

   <field id="email" type="text" model="applicant.email" label="Email address" class="ng-isolate-scope">
     <div ng-class="['field', isRequired()]" class="field"> <!-- Text/File/Password Field -->
        <label ng-bind="label" class="ng-binding">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      </div>
   </field>


  <div class="field">
     <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn secondary">
  </div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript libraries are loaded in this order:

1. jQuery 11
2. jQuery UI
3. Angular
4. My app.js

Scripts are loaded at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That means jQuery is not loaded. Do it first

Comment: In a normal situation that cannot happen. Are you sure that Angular and jQuery aren't having some sort of slap fight?

Comment: `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);` - what does it say?

Comment: And then `alert($.fn.jquery)`?

Comment: exist an error in $("#frmContact input:submit") is not soported view: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g14L78qg/1/) ..... others are well

Comment: @kshep92, what are you not telling us?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 see my edits for any missing information and the output of the both alerts is 1.11.2

Comment: Something very odd is going on, which I don't understand. Working with a copy of your page, try removing all traces of angular and see if those selectors work. If they do, then start building the page back up and see what makes it break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the hand that held the knife to my throat was my own.

Earlier in the application's development it was useful to add a couple helper methods on the `Object` prototype by doing `Object.prototype.findId = function() { ... }`. Turns out this raised all sorts of hell when trying to perform the `find()` method in jQuery.

I fixed it by turning this:

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... }
```

into this

```
var specialObject = function(object) {
   return {  
     myMethod: function() { ... }
   }
}
```

I didn't realize that my earlier approach was such bad practice until I read this: [Extending Object.prototype JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript)

Thank you all for your help, guys.

Comment: Aha, all is revealed!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS comes with [JQLite](https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/wiki/UsingJQLite), a lightweight smaller verison of jQuery, which is the one you are using here and that gives you unexpected results.

In order for Angular to works with the full jQuery, you need to make sure that **you load jQuery *before* Angular**. So watch your `<script>` tags order.

Comment: But even under jQLite, an unsupported selector shouldn't give "undefined is not a function" .... should it?

Comment: Well it's possible if somehow internally it tries to dynamically create a function based on the selector or any shadowy things like that. Is it the `find` method itself which is undefined or the error happens deeper into angular code? Try to log simply `$("#frmContact").find` to see if the function itself exsists.

Comment: There's something that the OP isn't telling us because even an invalid/ unsupported selector should give rise to an empty jQuery selection.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 not really, JQLite doesn't behave exactly the same and an empty selector returns `null` if I'm correct. Try to open an empty tab in the Chrome browser and write `$('.nothing');`, it should give you null. However I am not certain that Chrome defaults to JQLite or yet another jQuery subset.

Comment: floribon, interesting, thanks, If I had Chrome available, I would try, and If the OP would post some feedback, we would know if your tag order theory was correct.

Comment: @floribon jQuery is loaded before Angular. See my edits.