# What is the Javascript equivalent of Python's get method for dictionaries

Tags: javascript

Python's get method for dictionaries lets me specify what should be returned if a key doesn't exist. For my current case I want a dictionary returned. How do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: dict['key'] || default

Comment: There are also getters and setters in js...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of javascript object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Answer (score 12):

There is no javascript equivalent of the python dictionary get method. If you would write it yourself, as a function, it would look like this:

```
function get(object, key, default_value) {
    var result = object[key];
    return (typeof result !== "undefined") ? result : default_value;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var obj = {"a": 1};
get(obj, "a", 2); // -> 1
get(obj, "b", 2); // -> 2
```

Note that the requested key will also be found in a prototype of obj.

If you really want a method rather than a function (`obj.get("a", 2)`), you need to extend the prototype of Object. This is generally considered a bad idea though, see [Extending Object.prototype JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript)

Comment: I quite like the readability of this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

With modern javascript you can use the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
const result = obj[key] ?? default;
```

This will return the default value if `key` doesn't exist in `obj`. It will also return the default in cases like `{myKey: undefined}` or `{myKey: null}`, which may or may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: This is the javascriptic equivalent to the pythonic `dict.get()`.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript has no helper feature to do that. You need to test explicitly.

```
if ("myProperty" in myObject) {
    return { another: "object" };
} else {
    return myObject.myProperty;
}
```

You can use a ternary operator to do the same thing with less code.

```
return ("myProperty" in myObject) ? myObject.myProperty : { another: "object" };
```

Comment: Will this also check the prototype?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Yes. (You can use `hasOwnProperty()` if you want to exclude properties inherited from the prototype).

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in ...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the logical OR like this:

```
foo.bar || 'default'
```

If checks is foo.bar is falsy, so it returns 'default' if bar is undefined.

You just need to care, that foo is an object. Otherwise a ReferenceError is thrown.

Comment: Stuart's answer is better. This one will return default for ANYTHING falsey. Stuart's one only does that for nully things.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a proxy for this (really new ):

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name in target?
        target[name] :
        "Default";
    }
};
var dictionary={"hi":true};
var dict = new Proxy(dictionary, handler);
dict.a = 1;
dict.b = undefined;

console.log(dict.a, dict.b,dict.hi); // 1, undefined,true
console.log(dict.new); //"Default"

 //the proxied object gets changed:

console.log(dictionary.a, dictionary.b,dictionary.hi); // 1, undefined,true
console.log(dictionary.new); //undefined
```

A proxy is an object that reflects all changes and requests trough an handler. In this case we can write/access propertys of dictionary normally, but if we access values that do not exist it'll return "Default"

Comment: For those as curious as I am: [MDN Documentation on proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
let obj = {"a": 1};
let default = 100
obj["a"] || default; // -> 1
obj["b"] || default; // -> 100
```

But! there are some limitation, if `!!obj["a"] === false` we always get default value... so it's better to just check if key in obj, to be completely sure.