# dict.get() for javascript to parse fetch data

Tags: javascript, python, json

Is there a way I can do this in javascript?

```
events_json = events.json()
for detect in events_json.get("detections"):
    print(detect["source_location"])
```

This didn't seem to work in javascript:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data[detections][i][source_location])
```

Any suggestions to get this working in javascript? I tried following this link but wasn't able to understand how to use it for this: [What is the Javascript equivalent of Python's get method for dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184794/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-get-method-for-dictionaries)

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're using, and add that to the question? It'll help us debug the problem.

Comment: "I tried following this link but wasn't able to understand how to use it for this" Then I don't understand how we're supposed to help you; other people on Stack Overflow already gave their best shot at explaining the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote `detections` and `source_location` so they'll be literals, not variables, just like you do in Python. You can also use `.` notation in JavaScript for property name literals.

```
data.detections.forEach(detect => console.log(detect.source_location));
```

Comment: I tried using that and that wont work for adding multiple commands. The => seems to stop everything else afterwards: `data.detections.forEach(detect => 
    console.log(detect.source_location)
    let text = "<b>Device: <b>" + detect.machine_name + "<br>";
    let pre = document.createElement('p');
    pre.innerHTML = text;
    console.log(text)
    pre.style.cssText += 'font-size:16px;font-weight:bold; width: 350px; word-break: break-word;'
    output.appendChild(pre);
    );` I think this is a start so I will google how to use this without the `=>` and that should fix everything

Comment: If the function body is more than one expression you have to put it in `{}`.

Comment: `detect => { statement1; statement2; ...}`

Comment: I was actually going to say that I learned how to fix it by googleing it and found out that I need {} after the =>. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp Then I found out that you were kind enough to answer as well. lol Thanks for helping me out here.